# gmail script to forward emails on a weekend

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

New to Gmail scripting been asked to set up for one of our users to forward emails she gets form a particular email address to the company director on a weekend so from Friday night 18:00 to Monday morning 07:00.

Company uses gmail for there emails so need a gmail script found a few online but nothing that does it for particular days and times.

Comment: Have you resolved this? You can try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using triggers.

For example, using the code that was provided in [sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,String))

```
MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com",
                   "replies@example.com",
                   "TPS report status",
                   "What is the status of those TPS reports?");
```

From there, you are allowed to customized whom are the message coming from/to and schedule it on a specific date.

Then from [Code.gs](https://script.google.com), edit > All your triggers, you will be able to set your triggers.
See image below:

[image: Triggers]